# Create new line after 15 characters in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a POS system for a Pizza shop. I have added a new textbox so the seller can add the home address and telephone of the client. But when the seller prints the receipt, I want a new line on the receipt for every 15 characters of the home address.

For example the seller adds the address with 25 characters, I want the first line on receipt to show the first 15 characters and then show the remaining 10 characters on a second line. Or we can do something else that in the 3-rd space creates a new line. Here is the code to print the home address on receipt.

```
offset += 20;

graphic.DrawString("Adr: ".PadRight(1) + String.Format("{0}",txtAddress.Text), font2, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startx, starty + offset);
offset += 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this as an extension method for some reason, but you get the idea:

```
   public static string Every15(this string str) {
        if(str.Length < 15)
            return str;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
            var ch = str[i];

            if(i % 15 == 0 && i != 0) {
                builder.Append("\r\n");
            }
            builder.Append(ch);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```